# If $f'(c) > 0$ , then there is a neighbourhood around $c$ where the function $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f'(c) > 0$ , then there is a neighbourhood around $c$ where the function $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing.

Is the statement correct? Can anyone please help me to prove or disprove that statement?

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous at $c$, then yes. Otherwise there are counterexamples.

Comment: Can you please tell me the counter example?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $c=0$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}x+x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$. Then $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=0\\ 1-\frac2x\cos\frac1{x^2}+2x\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\end{cases}$$ and $f'(x)$ is frequently negative in the neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Observe that $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @user661541 Why $f$ is not continuous ?

Comment: @cmi $f$ is continuous. $f'$ isn't.